# Url.Content(null) MVC 5 return a link

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, return-value

When my `DateReturned` is null, I want to add a link in my html that redirects me to `~/CohortSubscriptions/Edit` which allows me to add a `DateReturned`

```
@{
  var dateReturned = Model.DateReturned == null ? "" : Url.Content(Model.DateReturned);
}
```

When I do this my 2nd `Model.DateReturned` issues the following error:

> "can not convert from 'System.DateTime?' to 'String' "

What is the right way to write it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Url.Content` expects a `string`, not a `DateTime` object.

You can fix it by:

```
Url.Content(Model.DateReturned.ToString()); //you might want to specify a format.
```

Comment: it works thank you! now how do I write my "~ / CohortSubscriptions / Edit"? Because here I see it: ~ / CohortSubscriptions / Edit when it's null but not the link to click